# How can I dynamically create an NSMutableArray with the low-level runtime APIs?

Tags: reflection, nsmutablearray, objective-c-runtime

#### Intro

So I've been experimenting with the Objective-C low-level runtime APIs defined in `<objc/runtime.h` and following [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). You can see the results of my playing [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/1073294#file_array.m).

#### Problem

I've been able to dynamically create a simple Hello World through Objective-C through only the low-level runtime APIs and C (see the gist above). It works. Now I'm trying to dynamically create a `NSMutableArray` using the same technique. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
Class nsmutablearray = objc_getClass("NSMutableArray");

id array = class_createInstance(nsmutablearray, 0);
id arrayAfterInit = objc_msgSend(array, sel_registerName("init"));

// get the count
objc_msgSend(arrayAfterInit, sel_registerName("count"))
```

But it's giving me an error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray count]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSMutableArray count]!'`

But it works properly if I change the middle part of the snippet above to read:

```
id arrayAfterInit = objc_msgSend(nsmutablearray, sel_registerName("arrayWithCapacity:"), 10);
```

This is sort of confusing me since they should be equivalent. The first snippet should be equivalent to calling `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` which works as Objective-C syntax, but not when calling these C functions.

Any light shed on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled upon a workaround that... works... I've updated the gist to show it working...

Basically, instead of calling `class_createInstance`, you explicitly send an `alloc` message to the `NSMutableArray` Class object. This works:

```
id array = objc_msgSend(nsmutablearray, sel_registerName("alloc"));
id arrayAfterInit = objc_msgSend(array, sel_registerName("init"));
```

Which makes we wonder: what's the point of `class_createInstance` then (I'm creating a new SO thread for that one...)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I'd suspect that Apple does some runtime magic to swap in a specific subclass, doing magic. I bet the NSMutableArray, while the visible name, isn't the real implementation. There's been other cases of that in the past.

Comment: Yes there's no doubt some Apple magic going on behind the scenes. I guess I'm more looking for a solution/workaround rather then the *why*...